# Find exact probability of values in range using hist() R function

Tags: r, histogram

I'm taking an online course that is supposed to be teaching R, but when it comes to interpreting a histogram produced by the data the instructions are to "just eyeball it" without stating how to use code to solve the problem. The problem si about how many people will visit a site given a uniform prior for the probability of clicks. This is the code

```
n_samples <- 100000
n_ads_shown <- 100
proportion_clicks <- runif(n_samples,min=0,max=.2)
n_visitors <- rbinom(n = n_samples, size = n_ads_shown, prob = proportion_clicks)

# Visualize the results
hist(n_visitors)
```

The question states "Eyeballing the plot you just produced, what is the probability you will get 5 or more visitors because of the ad?"

How would I answer this question with code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the ratio of (A) times that you got more than 5 visitors to (B) the total number of times:

```
sum(n_visitors>5) / length(n_visitors)
```

Or, equivalently:

```
sum(n_visitors>5) / n_samples
```

Comment: even simpler with:
    ```mean(n_visitors > 5)```